# How to determine if a PC is safe after receiving a suspicious email message

Tags: malware, email, spam, email-attachments

I was checking my gmail account spam folder and I noticed an email sent by a known sender.

I thought it was flagged as spam by mistake so I opened it. Then I realized the content is the same as another email I sent the same person about a month ago. Even the subject is the same.

The sender's name is correct, but I checked the headers and the actual address is not the sender's. I checked it on various blacklist search engines but apparently it came clean, WHOIS has redacted data for privacy reasons but it seems to be just a case of spoofing.

The message also has an **encrypted .zip file** attached that was not present in the original mail. In the message there's a password to open the .zip file but there's no way I'm going to open the thing on my PC.

The mail content is pretty spooky, though. I mean, **it's an email I sent** and supposedly only the receiver and me knew about it. I want to make sure there's nothing wrong with my account/devices. I'm wondering if the mail was "stolen" through malware on one of my devices, or on the other person's. We both used gmail accounts.

I safely store my passwords using an appropriate encryption software (KeePass) and have 2FA enabled, I'm pretty cautious when browsing and checking my mail (stuff like checking link urls before opening them). The other person, on the other hand, stores his passwords on a plain text file (I literally saw him open it), so I suppose his security *could* be pretty lacking.

What should I do in this situation? How could I inspect the content of the .zip file without exposing my machine and/or my personal data? I was thinking of installing some linux distro on a virtual machine to check it out. Should I download the file on my PC and transfer it on the machine? Or should I open gmail from inside the machine itself and download the attachment? I'm worrying that the former method could expose my PC, while the latter could allow the collection of personal data.

Comment: A live Linux distro in a VM is not a bad idea. That's how a lot of people do malware analysis.

Comment: I'd say it's safe to download the attachment for the purpose of transferring it to the VM, as long as you don't open the zip file on the host machine.